# Trying to understand this code (creating a [char]range)

Tags: powershell

I have code that works, but I have no idea WHY it works.

This will generate a list containing each letter of the English alphabet:

```
[char[]]([char]'a'..[char]'z')
```

However, this will not:

```
[char]([char]'a'..[char]'z')
```

and this will actually generate a list of numbers from 97 - 122

```
([char]'a'..[char]'z')
```

Could any experts out there explain to me how this works (or doesn't)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Powershell 'a' is a [string] type. [char]'a' is, obviously a [char] type.  These are very different things.

```
$string = 'a'
$char = [char]$string
```

$string can be cast as a [char] because it is a string, consisting of a single character.  If there is more than one character in the string, e.g. 'ab' then you need an array of [chars], which is type [char[]]. The extra set of square brackets designates an array.

```
$string | get-member
$char | get-member
```

reveals much different methods for the two types.  The [char] type has .toint() methods. If you cast it as [int], it assumes the numeric ASCII code for that character.

```
[int]$char
```

returns 97, the ASCII code for the letter 'a'.

Comment: Ah! So that extra set of brackets means it is an 'type' array... Interesting :) Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In your second example, you are trying to cast an array of characters to a single character `[char]`. That won't work.  In the third example, the `'a'` is considered a string by PowerShell. So casting it to [char] tells PowerShell it is a single char.  The `..` operator ranges over numbers. Fortunately, PowerShell can convert the character 'a' to its ASCII value 97 and 'z' to 122. So you effectively wind up with 97..122.  Then in your first example, the `[char[]]` converts that array of ints back to an array of characters: a through z.